# Is it possible to find the objects which depend on a synonym?

Tags: sql-server, synonym

I tried `exec sp_depends @objname = 'sfel.elpc'` but I did not get any results, but I know the synonym is referenced in at least one stored procedure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this code is better:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%sfel.elpc%' and type = 'p'
```

this code give you a more limited list of objects.

Comment: **this code is better:**, huh? it is the same as my query (which I posted first).  You only changed it to _SELECT *_ and limit it to return only procedures (which will result in it missing views and functions that could contain the target string)

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%sfel.elpc%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm) by Red Gate, which is free. I'm by no means sure whether it supports synonyms, but might be worth a try if no other solutions are suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. I'm a fan of some of the red gate tools, but I was not aware of the one.

Comment: No worries - it's literally only just come out which is probably why you wasn't aware of it